A Problem with two programmers working on a program, one after another - Solution Verification
Below is a recreational math problem that I did with a friend.
Problem:
Greg and Bob are two computer programmers. They need to write a program. Either one could complete the program in $10$ hours working alone. Unfortunately, they only have 1 computer available, so only one person can work at a time.
Greg starts out at his maximum work rate, but gets tired, so his work rate decreases linearly to a minimum of $10\%$ of maximum after $10$ hours. Bob's work rate starts at zero and increases linearly to his maximum at $10$ hours. At the point where Greg's work rate is the same as Bob's work rate, Greg stops working and Bob takes over.  Assuming the clock starts for both Bob and Greg at the same time, how many hours will Bob have to work to complete the program?
Answer:
We  will call Greg's work rate: $GR$. We will call Bob's work rate $BR$.
$GR$ starts at some rate $x$, for convenience we'll call that $100$.  After $10$ hours that work rate decreases to $10$ Let $t$ be the time. We have:
$$GR = 100 -9t$$
If Greg does the work by himself, it will take 10 hours. Greg's average work rate is:
$$ \dfrac{100 +10}{2} = 55$$
Therefore, the total work done is $55(10) = 550$ units of work.
Bob's average work rate would also have to be 55 since he would also complete the work in $10$ hours.  Since he starts at 0 his maximum work rate at $10$ hours would be $110$
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{110+0}{2} &= 55 \\
BR &= 11t
\end{align*}
At some time $GR= BR$ so $100-9t = 11 t$ or $100 = 20t$ so $t = 5$.
At $t= 5$ we have $GR = 100 -9*5 = 55$. This is also $BR$ at $t = 5$.
Greg's average WR after $5$ hours is $(100 + 55)/2 =  77.5$, so Greg's total work
is $5(77.5)= 387.5$ or $70 .45\%$ of the total.
Bob's total work is $550-387.5= 162.5$ or $29.55\%$
Up to this point we agree with the answer in the magazine.
Now $BR$ starts at $55$ and increases until the work is done, We will call the time Bob takes to complete $t_2$. Bob's final work rate $= 11(5+t_2)$.  Bob's average work rate is:
$$ \dfrac{ 55 +11(t_2+5) }{2} $$
Let $B$ be Bob's work.
\begin{align*}
B &= t_2(55+11(t_2+5))/2 \\
162.5 &= t_2(55+11t_2 +55))/2 \\
162.5 &= t_2 (11t_2 +110)/2 \\
325 &= 11t_2^2 +110t_2 \\
0 &= 11t_2^2 + 110t_2 - 325 \\
0 &= t_2^2 + 10t_2 - 29.5454 \\
t_2 &= \dfrac{-10 + \sqrt{(100+4(29.5454)}}{2} = 2.3855 \,\, \text{hours} \\
\end{align*}
However, according to the magazine the correct answer is:
$$ 2.686 \,\, \text{hours} $$
We think we are right. Are we?

Let me see how far we agree. Let us simplify further and talk about Greg's workrate as:
$$
A(t)=100-9t
$$
showing as you said that:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{10}(100-9t)\ dt
&=\left[100t-4.5t^2\right]_{t=0}^{t=10}\\
&=1000 - 450\\
&=550
\end{align}
$$
so similarly we have Bob's workrate, $B(t)=kt$, matching the same amount of work after 10 hours:
$$
550=\int_0^{10}(kt)\ dt=0.5k\cdot 10^2
$$
which indeed implies $k=11$ so that Bob satisfies:
$$
B(t)=11t
$$
Now the problem becomes (multiplied by two to remove future fractions):
$$
2\int_0^5(100-9t)\ dt+2\int_5^s\ 11t\ dt=2\cdot 550\\
$$
and so:
$$
\begin{align}
Greg&: & 2A(5) &=\int_0^5(100-9t)\ dt=\left[200t-9t^2\right]_{t=0}^{t=5}=1000-9\cdot 25\\
Bob&: & 2(B(s)-B(5)) &=\int_5^s\ 11t\ dt=\left[11t^2\right]_{t=5}^{t=s}=11s^2-11\cdot 25
\end{align}
$$
combining this we get:
$$
1000-9\cdot 25+11s^2-11\cdot 25=1100
$$
rearranging yields:
$$
11s^2=600\iff s=\pm\sqrt{600/11} = \sqrt{54.\overline{54}} \approx 7.385489
$$
and subtracting Greg's $5$ hours, I at least end up with the same answer as you!
$$
Bob: s-5=\sqrt{\frac{600}{11}}-5\approx 2.385489\text{ hours}
$$
for Bob to finish the job.
